# Updating an MS Access database from VB 2015

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to update an MS Access database from VB 2015 code. The dataset info is not getting back to the database.

I've read the answers here which say you must not AcceptChanges before the update, but if this is commented out, then da.Update(ds) below gives:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional Information: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.
```

Database TestDb – One Table = TestTable – Design:

```
Name        Type               Size
--------    -------          ------
ID          Long Integer          4 Primary Key
Name        Text                255
NumberOne   Long Integer          4
NumberTwo   Long Integer          4
```

Contents:

TestTable

```
ID  Name        NumberOne   NumberTwo
1   EntryOne    1   
2   EntryTwo    2   
3   EntryThree  3   
4   EntryFour   4   
5   EntryFive   5
```

Note that the “NumberTwo” column is intentionally left blank.

---

Program DbTest.vb

1. On start, the program loads the database into the dataset. The <<, <, >, and >> buttons can be used to step through the data.
2. The Execute button fills the dataset’s “NumberTwo” column with the squares of the entries in the “NumberOne” column.
3. The Save button attempts to save the modified dataset back to the database via the data adapter. The database is then loaded into the second dataset in order to check whether the first dataset was properly saved back to the database. By then stepping through the data, it is revealed that the save FAILED.

My code:

```
'**********
' DbTest.vb
' Version 0.00
' MDJ 2015/11/11
'**********

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As NewOleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TestDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM TestTable"
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
    Dim intCurrentIndex As Integer
    Dim dSaved As Boolean = False
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dSaved = False
    txtError.Text = "No Exceptions"
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        txtError.Text = "OleDbException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As DataException
        txtError.Text = "DataException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtError.Text = "Other Exception"
        GoTo errExit
    End Try
    txtError.Text = "Error: ds Is Empty"
    ' Fill dataset from database
    da.Fill(ds)
    'Check if the Table is empty
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtError.Text = "No Error"
    End If
errExit:
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    'Since 0 is the first row
    intCurrentIndex = 0
    txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
    txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
    txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
    txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    If dSaved = True Then
        txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    'We move back only if we're not at the first row.
    If intCurrentIndex > 0 Then
        'Subtract one from the current index.
        intCurrentIndex = intCurrentIndex - 1
        txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
        txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
        txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
        txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        If dSaved = True Then
            txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You're already at the first record.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    'ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 is the index for the last row
    'We move forward only if we're not at the last row.
    If intCurrentIndex < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
        'Add one to the current index.
        intCurrentIndex = intCurrentIndex + 1
        txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
        txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
        txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
        txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        If dSaved = True Then
            txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You're already at the last record.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    'ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 is the index for the last row
    intCurrentIndex = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
    txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
    txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
    txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    If dSaved = True Then
        txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    Dim n1 As Integer
    Dim n2 As Integer
    'ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 is the index for the last row
    Dim intLastCount As Integer
    intLastCount = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    ' Process each record
    For intCurrentIndex = 0 To intLastCount
        n1 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne")
        n2 = n1 * n1
        ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo") = n2
    Next
    ' If this is commented out, then da.Update(ds) below gives:
    '   An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
    '   Additional Information: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.
    ds.AcceptChanges()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    txtError.Text = "No Exceptions"
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        txtError.Text = "OleDbException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As DataException
        txtError.Text = "DataException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtError.Text = "Other Exception"
        GoTo errExit
    End Try

ERRLOC:
    ' THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    '   The dataset is not being updated back to the data adapter

    ' Save dataset to database
    da.Update(ds)
ENDERR:

    ' Fill second dataset from database
    txtError.Text = "Error: ds2 Is Empty"
    da.Fill(ds2)
    'Check if the Table is empty
    If ds2.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dSaved = True
        txtError.Text = "ds2: No Error"
    End If
errExit:
    conn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Usually error like this are caused by one of two reasons. 1) The connection was closed (or never opened). 2) The DataSet was changed by call the constructor with 'new' before the data was updated.  I can't tell from youi code if the Form1 is the main form in the project, or called from another part of your code.

Comment: Thank you. 1) The connection was opened. I don't think I would have been able to get the data into the datasets otherwise. And I just tried commenting-out the two conn.close() statements - that made no difference. 2) The "New Dataset" statements only appear at the beginning of the class. 3) Form1 is indeed the main form of the project.

Comment: If the update command is absent, it usually means you do not have a primary key defined on your table. Before we even look at the rest of your code, you need to go into the dataset designer and get it to include an update query.

Comment: Thank you. ID is the primary key.

Comment: Apologies my previous comment was wrong - I was thinking of strongly-typed datasets.

Comment: I've added the "Primary Key" designation above to assist any others who may be reading this for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

The error message is telling you that the OleDbDataAdapter does not have an UpdateCommand defined for it. Probably the most common way to define the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand properties is to use an OleDbCommandBuilder object. For example

```vb
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
cb.QuotePrefix = "["
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding the OleDbCommandBuilder fixed it. I also added:          "Imports System.Data" and 
    "Imports System.Data.OleDb"  
to allow the system to find the OleDbCommandBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be experiencing similar problems, the correct and working code is posted below.

The database TestDb is located in the local \bin\Debug folder.

Form1 is the main and only form.

Form1’s devices include:

```
Five Label – TextBox combinations, arranged in a vertical column
Label1 Text = “ID” – TextBox Name = “txtID”
Label2 Text = “Name” – TextBox Name = “txtName”
Label3 Text = “NumberOne” – TextBox Name = “txtNumberOne”
Label4 Text = “NumberTwo” – TextBox Name = “txtNumberTwo”
Label5 Text = “da’s NumberTwo” – TextBox Name = “txtDaNumberTwo”

(Label4 – TextBox refers to the value in the DataSet)
(Label5 – TextBox refers to the value in the database)

Four buttons, side-by-side
btnFirst – Text = “<<”
btnPrevious – Text = “<”
btnNext – Text = “>”
btnLast – Text = “>>”

Two buttons, one above the other
btnExecute – Text = “Execute”
btnSave – Text = “Save”

One Label – TextBox combination
Label6 Text = “Error” – TextBox Name = “txtError”
```

---

The correct and working code:

```
'**********
' DbTest.vb
' Version 0.00
' MDJ 2015/11/11
'**********

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
' This is the connection to the local MS Access database.
' The database is needed in both the Debug and Release folders.
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TestDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM TestTable"
' The DataAdapter is the bridge between the database and the DataSet. 
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
' MUST INCLUDE:
' OleDbCommandBuilder statement is required for Insert, Update, and Delete
' as are the cb.Quote... statements below.
Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
' The DataSet is the internal working copy of the portion of the database which is being processed.
' More than one dataset may be open at any given time.
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
Dim intCurrentIndex As Integer
Dim dSaved As Boolean = False
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cb.QuotePrefix = "["
    cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
    dSaved = False
    txtError.Text = "No Exceptions"
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        txtError.Text = "OleDbException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As DataException
        txtError.Text = "DataException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtError.Text = "Other Exception"
        GoTo errExit
    End Try
    txtError.Text = "Error: ds Is Empty"
    ' Fill dataset from database
    da.Fill(ds)
    'Check if the Table is empty
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtError.Text = "No Error"
    End If
errExit:
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    'Since 0 is the first row
    intCurrentIndex = 0
    txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
    txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
    txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
    txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    If dSaved = True Then
        txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    'We move back only if we're not at the first row.
    If intCurrentIndex > 0 Then
        'Subtract one from the current index.
        intCurrentIndex = intCurrentIndex - 1
        txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
        txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
        txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
        txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        If dSaved = True Then
            txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You're already at the first record.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    'ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 is the index for the last row
    'We move forward only if we're not at the last row.
    If intCurrentIndex < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
        'Add one to the current index.
        intCurrentIndex = intCurrentIndex + 1
        txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
        txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
        txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
        txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        If dSaved = True Then
            txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You're already at the last record.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    'ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 is the index for the last row
    intCurrentIndex = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("ID").ToString()
    txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("Name").ToString()
    txtNumberOne.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne").ToString()
    txtNumberTwo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    If dSaved = True Then
        txtDaNumberTwo.Text = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo").ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    Dim n1 As Integer
    Dim n2 As Integer
    'ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 is the index for the last row
    Dim intLastCount As Integer
    intLastCount = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    ' Process each record
    For intCurrentIndex = 0 To intLastCount
        n1 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberOne")
        n2 = n1 * n1
        ds.Tables(0).Rows(intCurrentIndex).Item("NumberTwo") = n2
    Next
    ' MUST NOT DO THIS BEFORE UPDATING - IT LOSES ALL CHANGES
    'ds.AcceptChanges()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    txtError.Text = "No Exceptions"
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        txtError.Text = "OleDbException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As DataException
        txtError.Text = "DataException"
        GoTo errExit
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtError.Text = "Other Exception"
        GoTo errExit
    End Try

    ' Save dataset to database
    Try
        da.Update(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    ' Fill second dataset from database
    txtError.Text = "Error: ds2 Is Empty"
    da.Fill(ds2)
    'Check if the Table is empty
    If ds2.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dSaved = True
        txtError.Text = "ds2: No Error"
    End If
errExit:
    conn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out today that it may not actually be updating the db you think it should be. If you are running the program from Visual Studio while programming, take a look in the bin folder where it sticks the executable and have a look at the db file it has placed there.

The instructions from MS on updating work just fine:
[Miscrosoft Instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

VS can also auto generate the INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE commands for the db if you go into the DataSet TableAdapter configuration for each table.

You must have a primary key set for each table that you want to use UPDATE or DELETE with.